# Is there a way to pass translatable strings dynamically into an Angular component?

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization

I want to make an Angular component with configurable, translatable input options.

End behavior: I can input a list of objects to a component, and have an option to display translatable strings, based on the values in the component.

`<my-component [options]="options"></my-component>`

```
<div class="my-component">
  <div class="option" *ngFor="let option of options">
    <span>{{ option.title }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, since I'm using Angular's `i18n` directive, everything translatable needs to be in HTML.

[Issue to have this any other way is open since 2016, so safe to say it's not coming soon](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405).

I tried [a ng-content approach](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i18n-p0rn):

```
interface TranslateChildOption {
  title: string;
  i18nTitle: string;
}

translatableOptions: TranslateChildOption[] = [
    { title: 'Jou 1', i18nTitle: 'selector-jou-1'},
    { title: 'Jou 2', i18nTitle: 'selector-jou-2'},
]
```

Inside the parent component:

```
<translatechild [options]="translatableOptions">
  <span type="selector-jou-1">Bonjou 1</span>
  <span type="selector-jou-2">Bonjou 2</span>
</translatechild>
```

Inside the child component:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of options">
  <span>{{ item.title }}</span> | <ng-content [select]="item.i18nTitle"></ng-content>
</div>
```

But apparently ng-content is only for static content projection, so can't bind a value to the `select` property. [It's another issue that's open from 2016](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563).

Is there a way to do this (sanely), without resorting to hacky behaviour?

Comment: have you thought about creating a component with @Input() Binding and [ngSwitch] inside the template evaluating the i18nTitle string input?

Comment: @A.Winnen managed to create something with ng-template and a custom component https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i18n-porno

Answer (score 0):

Figured something out. This is a compromise on top of a compromise for passing translatable options via `@Input` decorator

Everyone who wants translatable options to pass them into a component defines a custom `x-translator` component

using the `let-x="value"` syntax the translator is given the type to look for. It's passed into the selector via `<ng-template>`

Inside the selector component, the passed `<ng-template>` is retreived and rendered using `ngTemplateOutlet` and `TemplateRef` in the `*ngFor` loop, and given context for the current item at hand, to give the translatable label type to each instance of `selector-translator` in the `*ngFor`.

Inside the `selector-translator` component, the label type inputted does an `*ngIf` to look for which translatable html string to display

If there's need for any static text, they can be done in html using `<ng-content select="[type]='selector-name'" i18n></ng-content>`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i18n-porno